# Fetch data in codeigniter construct function

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, construct

I try to fetch data from database in codeigniter construct function 
but getting undefined method error

controller-

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('Login');
$this->Login->getadminnav();
}
}
```

model-

```
class Login extends CI_Model 
{
public function adminnav()
{
$query="SELECT * from adminnav where status='1'";
$query->row_array();
return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got to load the model you are using first:

```
$this->load->model('login_model');
$this->Login->getadminnav();
```

And remember to rename the model to `Login_model`

Answer (score 0):

Try these pieces of code.

**Controller:**

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login');
        $this->Login->adminnav();
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
class Login extends CI_Model{
    public function adminnav(){
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = "SELECT * from adminnav where status='1'";
        $result = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**I am seeing in your code that-**

1. In controller you didn't start the second bracket after controller name.
2. You defined the function name as "adminnav" in model but called it as "getadminnav" in Controller
3. You didn't load the database in model (If you already loaded it in autoload.php then here is not needed)

Anyway please let me know whether your problem is solved or not.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling getadminnav() but in your model the method name is adminnav.and change model name Login to Login_model.
try this:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Login_model');
        $this->Login->adminnav();
    }
}
```

// model

```
class Login_model extends CI_Model{
    public function adminnav()
{
$query="SELECT * from adminnav where status='1'";
$query->row_array();
return true;
}
}
```